# How to add numbers from textbox together in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, textbox, kendonumerictextbox

Let's say for example there are two textboxes: in one textbox the user enters "5", then on the second textbox the user enters 5 numbers "1 2 3 4 5" the computer has to add those 5 numbers from the textbox two together and display them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is pretty easy next time listen in class. Also I'm pretty sure that you will not understand the given answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be:

```
var numbersText = yourTextBox2.Text;

var allNumbersAddedUp = numbersText.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

Don't forget

```
using System.Linq;
```

This is independent of what the user enters in the first textbox.

*As this seems to be a textbook homework, please do your own homework, read your textbooks and learn this by yourself instead of using ready-made solutions from the internet. One day I will have to work with you and I want to work with people who learned this instead of copied it from somewhere on the internet.*